# Firebase Sign Up with username. Cliend Side + Security Rules or Backend?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have implemented a Firebase SignUp with username, email and password. Basically what I am doing is:

> 1- Create user with email and password (if the username and email are not used by other users)

> 2- Add the username to the user

Like this:

```
firebase
  .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((currentUser) => {
    // Get the username from the input
    const username = this.usernameInput.current.getText();

    // Create a user with this username and the current user uid in the db
    firebase.createUserWithUsername(username, currentUser.user.uid); // <----------
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // ...  
  });
```

And my createUserWithUsername function basically do this:

```
createUserWithUsername = (username, userId) => {
  /*
    Create a document in the usernames collection 
    which uid (of the document itself, not a field) is the given username.
  */

  // Pass username to lowercase
  username = username.toLowerCase();

  // Initial user's data
  const data = {
    email: this.auth.currentUser.email,
    username,
  };

  return this.db
    .collection("usernames")
    .doc(username)
    .set({ userId })
    .then(() => {
      this.db.collection("users").doc(userId).set(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      throw err;
    });

  /*
    Pd: As firestore automatically removes empty documents, we have to
    assign them a field. The user's id is a good option, because it will help us to
    update usernames faster, acting like a 'Foreign Key' in a NoSql DB.
  */
};
```

My question is? Is it wrong to leave this code on the client side? Can it be a security problem? Do I need to move this to a cloud function / backend?

This is my firestore security rule for the usernames collection:

```
match /usernames/{username} {
  function isUsernameAvailable() {
    return !exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/usernames/$(username));
  }
  
  allow read: if true;
  allow write, update: if isSignedIn() && isUsernameAvailable();
  // TODO - Allow delete?
}
```

I would really appreciate any guide for this. Thank you.

Comment: I think you'll want to do this in a batched write or transaction, so that both writes succeed/fail in tandem. You can then use `existsAfter()` instead of `exists()` to check the data as it'll be if the write is allowed.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen thank you for the feedback! Why should I use transactions for this (I have never use them)? In my code I create a document in my usernames collection with the userid... Aren’t Firestore Documents created atomically?!

Comment: If the the new status of a document depends on the existing value in that document, that's when you need a transaction. If it doesn't, you'd use a batched write.

Comment: AHHHH!!! Yesss thank you man! Now if the username cannot be written or the userId, the whole operation fails!